# P(Y >84 | Y > 72) =?

Tags: probability

Scores on an examination are assumed to be normally distributed with mean 78 and variance 36.

If it is known that a student’s score exceeds 72, what is the probability that his or her score exceeds 84?

P(Y >84 | Y > 72) = [(Y > 84) and P (Y > 72)] / P(Y > 72) , after this step, I don't know what I need to do.

Would I have to covert this y into a z?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote:

$$
P(Y >84 | Y > 72) = \frac{P[Y > 84\  \& \ Y > 72]}{P(Y > 72)}
= \frac{P(Y > 84)}{P(Y > 72)}.
$$
Now let us note $Y = 78+  6G$, so that $G$ has a standard gaussian distribution.

$$P(Y >84 | Y > 72) = \frac{P(G > 1)}{P(G > -1)}.$$Eventually, use you [tables](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/gerstman/EpiInfo/z-table.htm):
$$
P(Y >84 | Y > 72)\simeq \frac {1-0.8413}{0.8413} \simeq 0.1886$$

Answer (score 1):

Well using the conditional probability, it boils down to P(Y>84)/P(Y>72). The Probability of having a score greater than 84 and greater than 72 is the same as the probability of being greater than 84. Simple as that. Calculate the probabilites by either using a chart or your knowledge about normal distributions.